# Spring and other socket

Tags: java, spring

Im creating an app that uses spring framework to show web pages but in the back-end i need to connect with a external device using socket. It means i will need a parallel applications:

- Spring: User Interface
- Parallel lopp: Communication with a device

I have an ideia that the communication will be in the controller, but how can i connect to the device before spring starts and retrive as global variable the connection reference?

Does anyone know how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need delay starting spring web app before communicaton with device? What you could do instead:

- start spring web app as usual. It will communicate with service called `DeviceStateService`
- `DeviceStateService` will be populated by pararell loop. Before device state is started, it may reply with `Optional<DeviceState>` or otherwise signall that DeviceState is not known.
- before `DeviceState` is known, your sevice may respond with `503 Service Unavailable` to show that it is not yet ready to accept traffic

Below I assume that your parellel loop (serversocket) and HTTP API are on same JVM, same Spring Context.

- `DeviceStateService` will be your serversocket. It can @Autowire `DeviceStateRespository`. You may use Netty (configure `io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` see http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#writing-a-discard-server). I am using that option and it works fine.
- You may also use Spring Integration TCP inbound channel adapter http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html.
  It may be better option, if you want to stay inside Spring ecosystem. 
  Note that Spring Integration is much bigger and it may be overkill just for single TCP endpoint.
- `DeviceStateRespository` will contain private variable of type DeviceState, and get/set operations (to manipulate `DeviceState` member variable).
- `DeviceStateApi` can `@Autowire DeviceStateRespository` in order to have access to `DeviceState`.

Comment: Thanks for our reply, but i didnt understand how may i do a parellel loop (serversocket) and send messages between spring controller and serversocket. I find something about it (https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/2t6cpj/is_spring_framework_a_good_choice_for_an_internet/)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are connecting to `stackoverflow.com` host on port `80`, the following could be your configuration:

### device.properties in classpath

```
device.ip=stackoverflow.com
device.port=80
```

### DeviceConnection - The Endpoint to initiate call on Socket and receive response

```
package com.test.device.connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DeviceConnection {
    private Socket socket;

    public DeviceConnection(String ipAddress, int port) throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
    }

    public synchronized String call(String request) {
        return "Send request using socket, read response and then return the value. To be Implemented.";
    }
}
```

### DeviceConfiguration - A connection factory which can read device.properties and create a DeviceConnection object

```
package com.test.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:device.properties")
public class DeviceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DeviceConnection getConnection() throws IOException {

        return new DeviceConnection(environment.getProperty("device.ip"),
                Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("device.port")));
    }
}
```

### ServiceClass - Some Service Implementation which can use the Connection Object to make call and respond to Controller/Another Service

```
package com.test.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceConnection connection;

    public String doSomeService(String input) {
        return connection.call(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 1) The call method is where should i send my message over tcp/socket?  2) I was looking the spring doc (https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) and i have an ideia to create the connection inside of the main method and when i want to send message over tcp/socket i just call devices method i will implement, what you think about it (I know that the spring wont handle it, but it is more simple)? Please, comment about.

Comment: @BrennoLeal, you are right! The call method will send the stream over socket object created, read the response and return it to the called method. Why I had given preestablished connection was as per your requirement and single connection available at application scope. In case the server can support multiple client connections, you can easily tweak it in Spring and it would be easy to manage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention!  So... If i have more devices to commmunicate, the better solution is create the connection inside of the main method and handlle with my own methods, disconsidering Spring ?

Comment: @BrennoLeal, I would suggest to go with Spring managed for the advantages of Dependency Injection and Properties Management. The sample code is for a connection to set open and reuse the same for request and response. If you have a pattern where you dynamically connect to a Set of devices, you may go for the approach you were referring to. in case I have 3 devices with specific functionality I would configure spring to make connections and then use it for communication. I would even create specific Service components to for each device functionality.

Comment: @BrennoLeal, you may refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html for more functionalities